# Two divs one scrolls and another is static

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have two divs sit next to each other, with one div that scrolls and another that is static. An example is [AirBnb's Map](https://www.airbnb.com/s/New-York--NY--United-States).

I'm having trouble getting the right bar to float to the right of the left bar. How can I have the left bar always take up 60% of the space, and the right bar always take up 40%? In the code below, the right bar is never displayed.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0qpmuLd/).

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 62px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#left-bar {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#right-bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-bar"></div>
  <div id="right-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0qpmuLd/1/)

```
#right-bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  //added
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `height: 100%` should be replaced with `top: 0;` for consistency with the left bar.

Answer (score 2):

It's missing the `top:0;` on `#right-bar`, you should also set `width:40%;`, and you don't need to set any rules on `#container`, or simply delete it, since fixed position is relative to the viewport.

**1. Fixed position approach:**

```css
#left-bar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#right-bar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-bar">
  <div style="height:1000px;">scroll</div>
</div>
<div id="right-bar">static</div>
```

**2. Flexbox approach:**

```css
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; } 
body {
  display: flex;
}
#left-bar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 40%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#right-bar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-bar">
  <div style="height:1000px;">scroll</div>
</div>
<div id="right-bar">static</div>
```

**3. CSS table approach:**

```css
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; } 
body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#left-bar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
}
#right-bar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60%;
}
#scrolling {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-bar">
  <div id="scrolling">
    <div style="height:1000px;">scroll</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right-bar">static</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That code seems unneccesarily complicated, especially the fixed positions (also the absolute one). How about this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ubgcas1a/

This uses inline-blocks and defined widths and heights:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 62px;
}

#left-bar {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#right-bar {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
```